# How to make scrollable sidebar fixed?

Tags: html, css, navigation, tailwind-css, sidebar

I came across the BetterDev sidebar in which, If we add content to it, the sidebar also scrolls. Is there a way to make that sidebar fixed and not scrollable? I tried sticky, corrected with top-0 and left-0, but it didn't work.

```
<div class="relative min-h-screen md:flex">

  <!-- mobile menu bar -->
  <div class="bg-gray-800 text-gray-100 flex justify-between md:hidden">
    <!-- logo -->
    <a href="#" class="block p-4 text-white font-bold">Better Dev</a>

    <!-- mobile menu button -->
    <button class="mobile-menu-button p-4 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700">
      <svg class="h-5 w-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>

  <!-- sidebar -->
  <div class="sidebar bg-blue-800 text-blue-100 w-64 space-y-6 py-7 px-2 absolute inset-y-0 left-0 transform -translate-x-full md:relative md:translate-x-0 transition duration-200 ease-in-out">

    <!-- logo -->
    <a href="#" class="text-white flex items-center space-x-2 px-4">
      <svg class="w-8 h-8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4M7.835 4.697a3.42 3.42 0 001.946-.806 3.42 3.42 0 014.438 0 3.42 3.42 0 001.946.806 3.42 3.42 0 013.138 3.138 3.42 3.42 0 00.806 1.946 3.42 3.42 0 010 4.438 3.42 3.42 0 00-.806 1.946 3.42 3.42 0 01-3.138 3.138 3.42 3.42 0 00-1.946.806 3.42 3.42 0 01-4.438 0 3.42 3.42 0 00-1.946-.806 3.42 3.42 0 01-3.138-3.138 3.42 3.42 0 00-.806-1.946 3.42 3.42 0 010-4.438 3.42 3.42 0 00.806-1.946 3.42 3.42 0 013.138-3.138z" />
      </svg>
      <span class="text-2xl font-extrabold">Better Dev</span>
    </a>

    <!-- nav -->
    <nav>
      <a href="#" class="block py-2.5 px-4 rounded transition duration-200 hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white">
        Home
      </a>
      <a href="" class="block py-2.5 px-4 rounded transition duration-200 hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white">
        About
      </a>
      <a href="" class="block py-2.5 px-4 rounded transition duration-200 hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white">
        Features
      </a>
      <a href="" class="block py-2.5 px-4 rounded transition duration-200 hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white">
        Pricing
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <!-- content -->
  <div class="flex-1 p-10 text-2xl font-bold">
    content goes here
  </div>

</div>
```

[Codepen Link of the above code](https://codepen.io/chris__sev/pen/RwKWXpJ)

Answer (score 0):

position:fixed;
left:0px;

a example could be: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp

shows a navbar in top but as you can see:

```
  position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
```

All you need to change is from top to left!
if it doesn't works, it could be the body position type, but in that i cannot help u bud.